# Border visit to China from Uttarakhand, India?

Tags: india, china, borders

I don't have many opportunities to travel, but will be visiting Derhadun, Uttarakhand, India this Spring.

I've always wanted to go to China and since I work with almost all Chinese co-workers, I would really love to say that I've been to China even if only for a brief moment.

Since Uttarakhand shares is in the northern part of India with a Chinese border, is there any possible place where one could cross the border into China just for part of a day?

Sadly, most of my searches on this topic thus far have related to border disputes.

Comment: There's a small part of the border which is _not_ in dispute, but of that segment, as far as I can tell there are no roads on the China side, and of course no border controls. You are likely to find military patrols, though.

Comment: So nothing like the USA/Mexico border where there's a tourist economy and legal border crossing. That's really too bad.

Comment: It's all inhospitable, mountainous desert terrain. Almost nobody lives there. Not the sort of place you would expect tourism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lipulekh Pass is the only place in Uttarakhand, India where the border crossing is allowed into China. But this is allowed only for the pilgrims that are part of The Kailash Mansarovar Yatra, a pilgrimage to Mount Kailash and Lake Mansarovar.

It is very unlikely that other people (other than pilgrims) are allowed in this route.

Comment: +1.  All other India/China border crossings, including the only one of any significance (Nathu La), are also closed to foreigners.