# Is it possible to go overland from Yangon to Kathmandu?

Tags: routes, overland, nepal, myanmar, kathmandu

How can I get to Kathmandu from Myanmar using land transport?

Comment: That's a nice question but have you done any research on your own?

Comment: I certainly did. Most of the threads I've seen encourage flying and since border situations change frequently I'm looking for input from someone that attempted this recently.

Comment: Then it would be great if you could point out in your question what you have found out already. :)

Comment: Oh, and it might be useful to know your nationality regarding necessary visa.

Comment: And I did a quick check and I don't quite see what is the difficulty of e.g. Yangon - India - Nepal? Myanmar to India is [reported doable](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Myanmar#By_land), travel within India should be doable and from there it should be relatively easy to cross into Nepal towards Kathmandu. So what is the point of your question? Note that Travel SE is a Q&A and not a collection of trip reports.

Comment: @mts: it's still pretty hard to get reliable info on crossing Myanmar's borders when you're not going back the way you came and you're not flying in and out of a major destination.

Comment: @hippietrail should the Q then focus on this part of the journey? Surely anything but crossing into India is not sensible?

Comment: @mts: OK that info looks a lot more helpful than what I could find on a previous trip! I would've thought crossing into India was the sensible way but actually when I was considering my Myanmar trip I wanted to go either China-Burma-India or India-Burma-China and did not consider any other possibilities. So maybe there's another good one? I think at the time Laos-Burma wasn't a possibility but is now, though that's not relevant for this OP.

Comment: @hippietrail going [via China is currently not an option](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/74386/32134) so India is your only choice left.

Comment: @mts: Indeed. My geography of that corner is imperfect but any other route would involve going *around* entire countries which would seem silly if the Myanmar-India crossing is now known to be doable. Well the China route is probably possible but really expensive since you'll need to hire a guide and lots of other painful stuff. Unless OP is a PRC citizen ...

Comment: @hippietrail note that the only border crossing between Nepal and China is closed (see linked question in above comment), so even with a guide and all the Tibet stuff needed you can still not do it. I will put in an answer later if nobody else has in the meantime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes, such a trip is doable, via India.

**Reasoning the route**

Outdated:
As I wrote in [this post, it is currently impossible to reach Nepal via land from China](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/76353/32134), leaving only [border crossings with India](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nepal#Get_in) in question.

Update:
The route from Tibet into Nepal is open again, meaning that you could in theory also consider routes via China. However the option via India still seems a lot more straightforward to me.

You do not specify your nationality nor preferred means of land-travel, so I will assume that visa are no problem and any means of transport besides flying are fine.

From Myanmar it is possible to get to India (more below). There are also border crossings with Thailand (open), Laos and China, but that would include huge detours. In fact since India does not have a border crossing with China that is open to [non-locals](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/India#By_car) or [non-pilgrims](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61033/32134), any itinerary not directly through India would include a detour through all of China via the [Karakorum highway](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73979/32134) into Pakistan and then India.

So Myanmar - India - Nepal it is.

**Getting from Yangon to the border**

Citing from [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Myanmar#By_land) again:

> A land border crossing exists between India and Myanmar at Moreh/Tamu. There have been confirmed reports of travellers crossing into Myanmar from India (and vice-versa), with their own transport as well as with permits arranged in advance. It is no longer required to have a permit to visit the Indian state of Manipur, but an MTT permit is required to enter or leave Myanmar at Tamu. This permit is readily available from MTT in Yangon (who will require you to book a tour guide) or a number of other agencies (who will not) for USD 80-100 per person. Most agencies require 20 working days to arrange the permit (but in some cases can do it faster), and can have it delivered to the border so that you do not need to return to Yangon to collect it.

("MTT" stands for "Myanmar Travel & Tours")

This is confirmed by e.g. plenty of [posts in the Lonely Planet Forum](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-mainland/topics/myanmar-india-land-border-crossing-at-tamu-moreh-open?page=42), e.g. post 414 reports from experience and recommends another travel agency as of 2016, this [blog reports similar from 2015](http://rovingsnails.com/index.php/2015/03/10/hitchhiking-from-myanmar-to-india-overland-crossing-at-tamu-moreh/) and [this one of 2016 reports a hassle or two](http://www.buzzingtravelers.com/?p=912) but made it as well. So I do not see any problems to this part of the journey judging from recent reports.

**Traveling within India (and to Kathmandu)**

Now I'm no expert on India but [Rome2Rio tells me that Manipur to Kathmandu can be driven](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Manipur/Kathmandu). I also see [train connections all over the place](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Rail_travel_in_India) in India and then you could [cross into Nepal by bus or renting a car with driver](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Nepal#Get_in).

The only thing left open would be permits for North-Eastern India. [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/North-Eastern_India#Get_in) has to say:

> Note that entry into the states of Sikkim, Arunachal Pradesh, Nagaland, Manipur and Mizoram requires a Protected Area Permit (PAP) for non-Indians and an Inner Line Permit (ILP) for Indian citizens. Permits are issued by the Ministry of Home Affairs, but the easiest approach is to get your Indian visa with a special endorsement allowing travel in the state you wish to visit. Individual travelers are generally granted 15 days (extendable once), but are allowed access only into major towns and sights; travels off the beaten track generally require a registered tour group of four or more people.
>
> As of 1 Jan 2011, the Government of India has decided to exclude the states of Manipur, Mizoram and Nagaland from the Protected Area regime notified under the Foreigners (Protected Areas) Order 1958. This programme is being trialled for one year. However, it is advised that travellers still print out the relevant news articles from local news sources such as the Nagaland Post and Morung Express to show to border officials.

Another post in the Lonely Planet forum claimed that said program has been extended to December 2017, so you should have no issues passing through, but might be better to check on this one again before you depart.

Comment: I added that MTT = Myanmar Travel & Tours but I don't know if it's  company or government agency, if it has just one office or branches at cities and tourist destinations, etc.

Comment: My Norwegian friends travelled all over northeast India roughly 2 years ago (second half of 2014) and tell me only one state now needed a special permit.